# SCCM Device not showing in Device Collection

Tags: sccm

I'm new to SCCM, and have been creating Device Collections based on our Computer Names.
I have the following query in the device membership rules - created automatically by going to the Criteria Tab and filling in the Critereon Properties window.

```
select
SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client 
from SMS_R_System inner join SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM on SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId 
where SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name like "Trolley1-%"
```

This code is supposed to find all devices that start with the name Trolley1-
It currently finds 7 - TROLLEY1-LPT16, TROLLEY1-LPT3..... and some others.

However it is missing several.  If I go to devices, and type Trolley1- into the filter, I can see 12 devices.  Admittedly 3 do not have the client on them as they have not been turned on since we installed SCCM, but at least one other TROLLEY1-LPT9 does not show up in the collection.  But under devices it is found, shows online, client, the correct site code, and active.

I have manually done an Update Memebership of the collection, and refreshed, it still doesn't show.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you use a limiting collection other than "All Systems" in you collection with the query or any form of exclude collection?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  There are no excludes, and the limit is All Systems.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't be easy to answer without insight as it is not a common problem. I would first check if your device is in All Systems or only in Devices to find out whether it is your query or something else. Also maybe check if the icon of your collection is still the hourglass (this would mean the refresh is hanging). Another general advise is to check the query again within the collection properties and not in "monitoring" as those are not synced. finally it might help to connect to sccm via wmi and execute the query there and check and compare with doing the same in sql on the db

Comment: Seems to have just been a timing issue. A couple of days later and the machines are now showing correctly.  Thank you for the help Syberdoor.

Comment: Glad it worked out. In this case my best guess would be that one collection was stuck updating. The whole process is sequential so if one completely unrelated collection cannot finish yours will not start to update even if you force it. The not really great but still best way to check if you happen to have that problem again is to look at your list of collections and manually check whether one has the hourglass as icon in place of the 3 displays that are the normal collection icon.